# Automatically copy entire row from one column to another when new data is added to a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master spreadsheet which contains a data log. The data log contains complex formulas, so I would like an entire row to copy to a different column as just values (no formulas) automatically when new data is added to the sheet. I started out creating a module with the following code that will only copy the first row repeatedly.

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim lRow1 As Long
Dim lRow2 As Long
Dim i As Long

Set sh = ActiveSheet

lRow1 = sh.Range("AE" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lRow2 = sh.Range("AM" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

With sh.Range("AE13" & ":AJ" & lRow1)
sh.Cells(lRow2, "AM").Resize(1, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
lRow2 = lRow2 + 1
End With
End Sub
```

I would really like this to happen automatically every time new data is added to the sheet. Please help and any information is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the `Worksheet_Change` event?

Comment: I would like too, I am just not really sure how to make that work.

Comment: Is new data being entered in a specific column?

Comment: Yes, new data is added to column AE:AJ, and this data needs to be copied or the same values populate AM:AR every time a new row is added to AE:AJ.

Comment: Do you only want the cells to be copied when all of the corresponding cells in AE:AJ are full? I'm assuming you enter data in AE:AJ cell-by-cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following: first check that `Target` is in columns `AE:AJ` using `Intersect`, and then ensure that all cells in `AE:AJ` are full before copying, using `CountBlank`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("AE:AJ"))

    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim rngToCopy As Range
    Set rngToCopy = Intersect(rng.EntireRow, Me.Range("AE:AJ"))
    
    If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(rngToCopy) > 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    On Error GoTo SafeExit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    With Me
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AM").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, 5).Value = rngToCopy.Value
    End With
    
SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```